# In RestClient RxJava is not working well with Observable in Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, rx-java

Getting **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable for method ApiInterface.login** when i am working with RestClient hit with **Observable** (RxJava)

```
    RestClient.getApiInterface().login(commonParams.getMap())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<PatientData>() {
                @Override
                public final void onCompleted() {
                    // do nothing
                }

                @Override
                public final void onError(final Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public final void onNext(final PatientData response) {                
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you share the API interface

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the interface definition, for your service. As @VinayagaSundar said, you should provide that code

Comment: ya the error was with RxJavaCallFactory . Thanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add following method call

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Sometimes not giving call to this method could also cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks . Yeah, in this code i missed out **.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())**

Also, the error was because of **.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())** while creating Retrofit.Builder.create()  & in order to include **RxJavaCallAdapterFactory** in RxJava (not RxJava2 ) this dependency worked :  **compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'**